# I want to make circular list with common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I want to make circular list with common lisp using rplaca or rplacd.

```
lambda (x) (cons (car x) (cons (rplacd (cdr x) (car x))))
```

I made code like above, but i think it is not what I want to.
How I make circular list?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you will always get a stack overflow when you try to print a circular object and [`*print-circle*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pr_cir.htm) is `nil`. So, start with

```
(setq *print-circle* t)
```

Now, there are many ways to create a circular list:

```
(defparameter *my-circular-list* (list t))
(setf (cdr *my-circular-list*) *my-circular-list*)
==> #1=(T . #1#)
```

Note how the [circular](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/glo_c.html#circular) list is [printed](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_a.htm) with [`#=`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_dho.htm) so that it can be [`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm):

```
(defparameter *my-circular-list-1* '#1=(t . #1#))
```

Warning: `(equal *my-circular-list* *my-circular-list-1*)` will hang because it will infinitely descend into the circular structures.

You can also try this:

```
(setq *print-circle* nil
      *print-length* 4)
(print '#1=(a . #1#))
==> (A A A A ...)
(setq *print-length* 10)
(print '#1=(a . #1#))
==> (A A A A A A A A A A ...)
```